# How can I include and use USPS shipping module in my Broadleaf React Starter application

Tags: reactjs, shipping-method, broadleaf-commerce, usps

I want to include and use USPS shipping module in my Broadleaf react starter application : [reactStarter](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/ReactStarter).

I added blc-usps depenndency: [blc-usps](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.broadleafcommerce/broadleaf-usps/1.6.0-GA).

I also registered on https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm and got credentials which I included in common.shared.properties:

```
usps.password=[my USPS provided password]
usps.user.name=[my USPS provided username]
```

And I added this configuration for USPS in applicationContext-entity.xml inside core application:

```
<bean id="blShippingCalculationService" class="org.broadleafcommerce.vendor.usps.service.USPSShippingCalculationServiceImpl">
    <property name="uspsCharSet" value="${usps.charset}"/>
    <property name="uspsPassword" value="${usps.password}"/>
    <property name="uspsServerName" value="${usps.server.name}"/>
    <property name="uspsServiceAPI" value="${usps.service.api}"/>
    <property name="uspsUserName" value="${usps.user.name}"/>
    <property name="failureReportingThreshold" value="10"/>
    <property name="httpProtocol" value="${usps.http.protocol}"/>
    <property name="uspsShippingAPI" value="${usps.shipping.api}"/>
    <property name="rateRequestElement" value="${usps.rate.request.tag}"/>
    <property name="uspsRequestValidator">
        <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.vendor.usps.service.message.USPSRequestValidator">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.common.util.EnvironmentFactoryBean">
                    <constructor-arg value="${usps.rate.request.validator}"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="uspsRequestBuilder">
        <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.common.util.EnvironmentFactoryBean">
            <constructor-arg value="${usps.rate.request.builder}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="uspsResponseBuilder">
        <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.common.util.EnvironmentFactoryBean">
            <constructor-arg value="${usps.rate.response.builder}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and I cannot run the application since I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blShippingCalculationService' defined in class path r
esource [applicationContext-entity.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed 
to instantiate [org.broadleafcommerce.vendor.usps.service.USPSShippingCalculationServiceImpl]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/broadleafcommerce/common/vendor/service/exception/ShippingPriceException
```

Can you please provide me some solution ?